# Change Edge color in NetworkX Graph depending on what edges has been visisted by Dijkstras algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

i am trying to change the color of the edges between the nodes that is visisted by dijkstras algorithm within the python package NetworkX. The grap that is being used in this project is the inbuilt nx.karate_club_graph()

The expected result if i were to have the code for it is that the the color of the edges between the visited nodes would be red. The current result is all the visisted nodes highlighted, but with the edges being the default black color.

I've looked at different solutions from stack overflow about changing edge color, and i just cant get them to work for my specific scenario.

here is the code that i've made.

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.karate_club_graph()

nodes = G.nodes()

position = nx.spring_layout(G)
color = {"Mr. Hi": "#3DA3F5", "Officer": "#E0D91B"}
dijkstra_route = nx.dijkstra_path(G, 24, 16)
colors = ["red" if n in dijkstra_route else color[G.nodes[n]["club"]] for n in nodes] 
nx.draw(G, position, node_color = colors, with_labels = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `edge_color` to `nx.draw()`

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.karate_club_graph()

nodes = G.nodes()

position = nx.spring_layout(G)
color = {"Mr. Hi": "#3DA3F5", "Officer": "#E0D91B"}
dijkstra_route = nx.dijkstra_path(G, 24, 16)

colors = ["red" if n in dijkstra_route else color[G.nodes[n]["club"]] for n in nodes]

dijkstra_edges = []
for index in range(0, len(dijkstra_route) - 1):
   edge = (dijkstra_route[index], dijkstra_route[index + 1])
   dijkstra_edges.append(edge)

edge_colors = ["red" if edge in dijkstra_edges else "black" for edge in G.edges()]


nx.draw(G, position, node_color=colors, edge_color=edge_colors, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xpmm.png), which is close to what you want, although I can't figure out why edge `(31,0)` isn't colored